# Overlap between Wired vs WiFi vulnerabilities

Tags: network, wifi, man-in-the-middle, vulnerability, wireless

This is a fundamental question, but, I'm interested in understanding the "venn diagram" of attack vectors between wired and Wi-Fi connections.

What are the attacks that both wired and Wi-Fi are vulnerable to? And what are the attacks that are exclusive to Wi-Fi?

What I know so far: Evidently, I know that we can prevent airbourne attacks (such as sniffing packets over the air). MiTM attacks are harder to pull off because the attacker would need to modify the cable. I'm sure there is more to this, but, I'm hoping to know more concretely where the attack vectors overlap and where they don't.

Comment: WiFi *is* Ethernet.  Your question is unclear.

Comment: @Chenmunka Hmm, sorry. I meant wired connections vs WiFi.

Comment: @Chenmunka I just updated the question. Hope it makes sense now.

Comment: Modify an Ethernet cable is easy. A skilled attacker can add two connectors to a cable in minutes, plug them into a bridge and silently sniff or change any packet.

Comment: @ThoriumBR Interesting. Thanks for the insight.